# Save column name in a variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want to save column name in this code to set @Y2:

```
DECLARE
    @H AS NVARCHAR(50),
    @X AS FLOAT,
    @Y1 AS FLOAT,
    @Y2 AS FLOAT
    -- , @COLNAME AS NVARCHAR(50)

SET @H = 'PROD1';
SET @X = 10;

IF @H = 'PROD1'
    SELECT
        @Y1 = CASE
                WHEN @X = 10 THEN
                    [CODE1]
                    -- @COLNAME = 'CODE1'
                ELSE
                    [CODE2]
                    -- @COLNAME = 'CODE2'
            END,
        @Y2 = RIGHT(@COLNAME, 1)
    FROM TABLE_NAME;
    .
    .
    .
```

Now the @Y1 variable takes the value of **[CODE1]** or **[CODE1]** and it isn't possible to write another line inside the case environment. How can I modified that?

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking here; you need to elaborate.

Comment: @Larnu, I want to remove '--' in the code, but I got error.

Comment: Removing the `--` works fine for me: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wq166x85). If you are getting an error, tell us what the error is, and provide a [mre].

Comment: @Larnu, Incorrect syntax near '@COLNAME'. You don't remove all '--'.

Comment: If you mean within the `CASE` expression, `[CODE1] @COLNAME = 'CODE1'` *isn't* valid syntax; what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @Larnu, Set Y1 in a case, and I have to depend to name of column that Y1 gives value from that column, set Y2 (from last number appear in column name).

Comment: You *can't* set a variable *within* a `CASE` expression; you can set the value *returned* from a `CASE` expression to a variable, but you can't `SET` within it. `CASE` (as I mention) is an **expression**, it returns a scalar value.